# How to transpose dataframe by specific column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, transpose

I am trying to wrangle some data for my masters thesis, and am struggling to restructure a data frame.

I have a data frame that looks like this [table, with three variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5rMkT.png)

Basically I want to flip it on its side so that Sample goes along the top with two rows underneath for farm and year. I have tried these approaches so far (dataframe is called labnums):

```
labnums <- labnums %>%
  spread(sample, farm + year)

labnums <- xtabs(year + farm~sample, labnums)
```

however neither work. Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work? (Also sorry for having to use an image, I've never posted on here before)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide dput output of few rows (3-4) of your data ? And, how would the output looks like

Comment: For posting on SO, formatting can make a huge difference. You can read [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and see that indenting your code is as straight-forward as highlighting the chunk and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>. Furthermore, realize that by posting an image and asking us to run code against your data, you are asking us to transcribe your image into usable data. There are a few good refs for how to improve question quality, such as: [reproducible questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) and [SO mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: maybe you're only looking for the `t` function ? `df <- as.data.frame(t(df)); df <- setNames(df,df[3,]); df <- df[-3,]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be nice if you showed an example, how the result should look like. My best guess now is this:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(farm = c(3, 5, 5, 5), 
                 year = c(2017, 2018, 2017, 2017),
                 sample = c(116, 24, 88, 105))

t(df) 
#>        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> farm      3    5    5    5
#> year   2017 2018 2017 2017
#> sample  116   24   88  105

df %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()
#>          V1   V2   V3   V4
#> farm      3    5    5    5
#> year   2017 2018 2017 2017
#> sample  116   24   88  105
```

Is it what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have managed to produce that dataframe, but I was hoping to have that but with the samples as the names of the columns, Ralcyone.116, Ralcyone.24, Ralcyone.88 etc.

Comment: Then you should read the comments to your question because i answered that 1 hour ago ;)

Comment: Hi, I actually tried your code and it didnt work, it just made the table as above

Comment: see my answer below (I had to add a `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` for the names to be right)

Answer (score 2):

```
df <- data.frame(farm=c("BADU003","BADU005"),
                 year= 2017:2018,
                 sample= c("Ralcyone.116","Ralcyone.24"),stringsAsFactors = F)

# transpose matrix
df <- as.data.frame(t(df),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# set the names as the values of the 3rd row
df <- setNames(df,df[3,])

# remove 3rd row
df <- df[-3,]

#      Ralcyone.116 Ralcyone.24
# farm      BADU003     BADU005
# year         2017        2018
```

with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(df,key,value,-sample) %>% spread(sample,value) %>% column_to_rownames("key")
#      Ralcyone.116 Ralcyone.24
# farm      BADU003     BADU005
# year         2017        2018
```

Comment: I added a `tidyverse` version, it's cleaner code, but you need an additional package